# Convert nullable double to double type datatype

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have model class with lots of nullable double property in asp.net MVC 5 project

```
  public class ValueAddedTax
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? TaxableGoodsSalePrice { get; set; }
    public double? TaxableGoodsSupplementaryDuty { get; set; }
    public double? TaxableGoodsValueAddedTax { get; set; }
    public double? ZeroRatedSalePrice { get; set; }
    public double? ZeroRatedSupplementaryDuty { get; set; }
    public double? ZeroRatedValueAddedTax { get; set; }
    public double? ExemptSalePrice { get; set; }
    public double? ExemptSupplementaryDuty { get; set; }
    public double? ExemptValueAddedTax { get; set; }
    public double? TotalTaxPayable { get; set; }
  }
```

now in controller I want to create local variable and try assign all the property data into it

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddTaxInfo(ValueAddedTax valueAddedTax, int? id)
    {
        // Assagin Data
        double taxableGoodsSalePrice = valueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (valueAddedTax.CustomerInfoId != 0)
                return RedirectToAction("ValueAddedTax", "Customer", new {id = valueAddedTax.CustomerInfoId});

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
        }
   }
```

if any property value is null then i want them as 0 in local variable so that i can calculate.
how can i do this??

Comment: `TaxableGoodsSalePrice.GetValueOfDefault()`

Comment: `double taxableGoodsSalePrice = valueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice.GetValueOrDefault();` it is what i want. thank you brother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to write the logic yourself, you'd need something along the lines of:

```
// if this Nullable has an actual value...
if (valueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice.HasValue)
{
    // ...return the Nullable's value      
    return valueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice.Value;
}
else
{
    // return the default value of the double value type
    return default(double); // 0.0D
}
```

..which is pretty much what the built-in [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Nullable_1_GetValueOrDefault) can do for you:

> "Returns:
>
> The value of the Value property if the HasValue property is `true`; otherwise, the default value of the current Nullable object. The type of the default value is the type argument of the current Nullable object, and the value of the default value consists solely of binary zeroes."

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback off of trashrOx's answer but more consise ways.

If you are running C# >= 7.2 you can use the conditional operator:

```
double notNullVersion = ValueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice.HasValue ? (double)ValueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice : 0.0D;
```

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

or, if you are running C# >= 8.0 you can simply use the null coalescing operator:

```
double notNullVersion = ValueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice ?? 0.0D;
```

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

I, personally, find these ways simpler to read through in code. Hope this is helpful to an S.O.er out there somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer to the question is correct Microsoft suggests a different approach to this. I am writing it here for future readers.

According to Microsoft the `default` keyword returns `null` for Nullable value types. For example
`double? variable = default(double?); //sets variable to null` [reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)
for that reason we should use `GetValueOrDefault()`.

It worths to mention that explicitly casting  a nullable value type to a non-nullable type throws a null exception if the nullable is actually set to null.

*from the same link*

```
int? n = null;
//int m1 = n;    // Doesn't compile
int n2 = (int)n; // Compiles, but throws an exception if n is null
```

So the suggested approach would have been `valueAddedTax.TaxableGoodsSalePrice.GetValueOrDefault(0)` [reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#conversion-from-a-nullable-value-type-to-an-underlying-type)